# Ethernet is much slower than Wi-Fi, but only on specific user

Tags: networking

Wi-Fi 5GHz: 340 mbits

Ethernet: 190 mbits

Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller

I'm using a Cat5e that supports 1 gbit, I've tried another 5e cable too.

I've tried updating the drivers, that didn't help.

The "Speed & Duplex" is set to AUTO, and the link speed is 1 gbit.

I tried creating a new user and running a speedtest, this time it achieved full speed, so the problem is specific to my main user.

I've tried ethernet on another computer, and was able to reach the same speed as Wi-Fi, so I know it's just this PC that has the problem.

Windows 10 Pro 1709 64 bit

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the problem happen in Safe Mode?

Comment: Yes, it also happens in Safe Mode

Comment: What is the "speedtest" you are using  to measure the bandwidths?

Comment: I've used speedtest.net. "Killer" has a program, Killer Control Center, which also has a speedtest; they achieve the same speed.

Comment: Does the problem occur if you logon as the affected user, then leaving that account logged in, switch to another user account that you've previously established isn't affected?

Comment: 1. Boot up PC 2. Sign in as problematic user 3. Sign out 4. Sign in as other user 5. Speedtest - is this what you meant? If so, the other user still has full speed, even after first being signed in to problematic user

Comment: no, for step 3 don't sign out, instead [switch users](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/3-ways-to-switch-user-in-windows-10.html). This keeps the first user's applications running.

Comment: The problem is even more specific, it's with Chrome. I tested with Chrome on problematic user, but with Edge on good user. Problematic user is able to reach 340 mbits with Edge too - I turned off "hardware-accelerated video decode" in Chrome not long ago, maybe that's why.

Comment: Perhaps try running chrome in [safe mode](https://readwrite.com/2010/02/08/extensions_broke_your_browser_how_to_enter_safe_mo/)?

Comment: I just cleared cookies and cache for speedtest.net, now it's able to reach 340 mbits. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: fixed. It wasn't a problem with the user, it was a problem with the cache and the cookies on speedtest.net. After deleting the cache and cookies for this site, all other sites were also able to reach 340 mbit

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, it appears the issue is due to your Chrome browser, not the user account or network interfaces.

You can try running Chrome in [Safe Mode](https://readwrite.com/2010/02/08/extensions_broke_your_browser_how_to_enter_safe_mo/) to determine if there's a faulty extension installed, or clear your browser's cache.